# iPhone, WMI, iis service

Tags: c#, .net, iphone, iis, wmi

I am thinking about writing an application that will monitor IIS Service with iPhone, and send notification, perform resets if an IIS goes down.

I dont want to create a web service to do that but rather connect to a machine, specifying credentials and then get data from the IIS Service state.

Is it even possible?

Is it possible with iPhone?

**I need to make this app generic enough for people to use with their hosted web sites and monitor their health and being able to reset it and/or recycle AppPools. I cant implement a service for any hosted environment. I need to be able to give the iPhone users an ability to connect to their host and once you are connected to the machine and authenticated to perform WMIs the phone users can mess with the iis.  Is it possible?**

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by "their host". It sounds like a service. For example, my understanding your saying "connect to their host" is kind of Windows remote connection like, which is actually a feature or service on their hosts. If you enable remote connection, there is a host service enabled there ready for any connection request. Instead of of this kind of Windows feature, you can easily create a console based on Kayak and let it running. It is a HTTP service ready for your specified action: check and reset IIS, in your control.

Answer (score 1):

I see your point not wanting to use web service because you want to monitor and reset IIS service, while web service is based on IIS. How about RestFul service? I have created RestFul service based on [OWIN](http://owin.github.com/spec.html) (Open Web Interface for .Net) and [Kayak](http://kayakhttp.com/).  Kayak may have some examples there.

The cool thing about those tools or lib is that the framework is very simple and does not rely on IIS. You can provide two URLs, one for get and one for post.  The former is to get status of IIS server and post is to reset IIS. Those services can be just XML of JSON based objects and it will be up to the the OWIN service to do the job on the back end. Another great feature of this is that you can even create the service in a console app or any other ways (Windows service or Window Form in system tray) on WindowsXP or Home version. The app will provide RestFul service based on HTTP with specific port.

RestFul service is available for variety of platforms, including iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Although IIS supports remote administration I doubt there's a way to implement it on the iPhone easily.

You could write an actual Windows Server (not a web service) you could connect to with a socket which can do all the monitoring instead though.